# Json to Java-Getting value of a particular attribute,avoid mapping of all attribute

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization

I am new to JSON and I searched through many answers in the site related to converting JSON to JAVA Object.
Here is my issue.

I have a big JSON data and I want to extract a few information from it.It contains many object like personalInfo,Friends,CareerInfo etc. I want to get value of some attribute of Friends lets say.

After going through all the solutions,I concluded that I have to create a class which maps all the attribute of the JSON.

I don't want to create class mapping every data.**Is there a  way where I can avoid creating a class for all data in JSON and just get values of some attribute inside one object?**

just to be more clear:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lets say here I just want the value of ID and Abbrev inside GlossEntry.Creating a GlossEntry class is fine but I don't want to go in trouble of creating a glossary class as there are many datas.

Comment: Every JSON library for Java will allow you to do this, yes.

Comment: Can you provide an example where something like this is done.I cant find any tutorials for the problem described above.Everywhere they are mapping json data with a class

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

- Implementing a parser by yourself.
- Using JSONObject (http://json.org/java/).

If you need a better performance, you should consider using GSON (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), but you will need to create classes and write some mappings to create a better Java object representation.

Comment: Not only will Gson allow you to access the parsed tree directly (See: `JsonParser`) but so will Jackon which is the far more performant library if you're talking about speed.

Comment: Hi,thanks.How to implement a parser?Please provide some reference

Comment: @BrianRoach I already read an article (I don't remember where) that GSON (nowadays) has a better performance than Jackson.

Comment: Actual benchmarking disagrees - https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki but honestly ::shrug:: either is fine for 99.9% of the people out there.